# Bootloop Galaxy S2 GT-I 9100

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, boot-loop

My phone( Galaxy S2 GT-I 9100)  is in bootloop . I have installed cwm v6.0.3.6 and I have done wipe cache and wipe dalvik , after that I have installed cm10 but the problem doesnt fixed . So how can I fix this problem? I don`t want to lose my pictures and music.

Comment: If you can reach Recovery mode which IMO shouldn't be affected by boot-loop, then use ADB from there to transfer Pictures and Music or any other data into PC. CWM should be having ADB support by default. Access ADB from PC.

Comment: I have installed CM11 but now it brings error "No external storage available"